# Understanding Proof by Contrapositive

Tags: proof-writing

This is a question from my textbook, and I'm pretty sure I have the answer, but I am having trouble writing out what I am thinking.

Prove: *If $n$ is an integer and $3n+2$ is odd, then $n$ is odd.*

*Contrapositive: If $n$ is even, then $3n+2$ is even.*

$n$ is even, by definition $n = 2k$, where $k$ is an integer.

Plugging in $2k$ into $3n+2$, we have $3(2k)+2$.

$3(2k)+2 = 6k+2 = 2(3k+1)$, which means $3n+2$ is even.

*Since if $n$ is even, then $3n+2$ is even. Negating the conclusion of the original conditional statement implies that it's hypothesis "$3n+2$ is odd" is false, therefor if $3n+2$ is odd, $n$ is odd.*

What am I missing, or what can I do to make this less awkward? Or am I wrong about the proof on the most basic levels?

Comment: It can be proved directly: $\rm\ 3n\!+\!2\,=\, 2k\!+\!1\,\ is\ odd\:\Rightarrow\: n\,=\,2(k\!−\!n)-1\,\ is\ odd.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct, though you could improve on it by writing it in essay style, cutting down on some verbosity, and by mentioning that $3k+1$ is also an integer. For example, you could write something like this:

We try to prove the contrapositive. If $n$ is even, then $n=2k$ for some integer $k$, so $3n+2=3(2k)+2=6k+2=2(3k+1)$ where $3k+1$ is an integer, making $3n+2$ even.

Note that proofs can be written with varying degrees of detail. In beginning courses, instructors prefer to see more detailed proofs to ensure students really understand what they are writing.

Comment: Up to how much? Do I remove everything after "Since if n is even, then 3n+2 is even."?

Comment: So it's better to write out explicitly what I have up there? (As in, "3(2k)+2=6k+2=2(3k+1), which means 3n+2 is even." should have been a bit more spelled out)

Comment: I see. I have trouble trying with proofs and explaining proofs so thank you!